Unable to hot-reload using cl-gtk4
I'm using the gtk4 bindings in Common Lisp from https://github.com/bohonghuang/cl-gtk4.
The description says code can just be hot reloaded, but the main function seems blocking and it doesn't seem like I can re-compile the code (I'm using Slimv).
What's missing in my setup? Do I need to run the main function differently?
I can run the examples without any issues, and I'm using Neovim on Ubuntu 24.04, Slimv and SBCL.
An example to reproduce:
(ql:quickload :cl-gtk4)

(gtk4:define-application (:name test-app :id "org.testorg.testapp")
  (gtk4:define-main-window (window (gtk4:make-application-window :application gtk4:*application* ))
    (setf (gtk4:window-title window) "Test App"
          (gtk4:window-default-size window) '(800 600))
    (gtk4:window-present window)))

When evaling the snippet with ,d for SlimvEvalDefun(), and running it with (test-app) in the repl it works as expected, but if I change the window title and re-eval it with ,d it doesnt update (I could be wrong but it seems like the (test-app) call is blocking, potentially preventing it from reevaluating.

I think that you will need to provide more information. "What's missing in my setup?" Are you running under Linux, MacOS, Windows? Are you using MSYS2? Are all of the library dependencies listed on the cl-gtk4 github page satisifed? "Do I need to run the main function differently?" How are you currently running the main function? It would help if you provided a [mcve].

I added some context around my setup, will provide a minimal example later today

I added some extra example code - I will test if I can reproduce the same behavior with emacs

looks like the same setup straight up fails in slime/emacs (it crashes) with a mysterious error
Received signal 8 @ 72a131d93d8b in non-lisp tid 42234, resignaling to a lisp thread.
The integrity of this image is possibly compromised.
Continuing with fingers crossed.

Process inferior-lisp floating point exception (core dumped)```


Running the example straight in SBCL works fine - maybe slime is running some extra bits in a different thread causing havoc? either way, I can't get hot reloading to work in emacs either

I can't reproduce this in Emacs Slime. I put your gtk4:define-application form in a file, quickloaded cl-gtk4 into the repl, and did C-c C-k to compile and load the file into the repl. Then I ran (test-app) from the repl and the window came up. Then I changed the title bar string and again did C-c C-k, and the change was immediately put into effect.

Interesting, thanks for repro-ing. Seems like something's off in my setup, which OS are you on? I'm on ubuntu 24.04
Just to read your second comment back to back to you, while I can't run extra code in the repl since it's blocking, compiling code will still work and have affects on the current repl session?

I am using Windows. Yes, you can edit source files, recompile, and load the result into a running repl. With Slime, from a source file buffer, you can do C-c C-k to compile an entire file and load it into the repl, or you can do C-c C-c to compile a defun and load it into the repl. This is what it looks like the cl-gtk4 live reloading example is doing. I haven't used Slimv, so I'm not sure how things work there.
